# How to recover useful answers from automatically deleted questions

Tags: bug, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, migration, vote-to-undelete

**TLDR: Stack Exchange automatically deleted useful reference information. How do I recover it?**

[About five years ago, I asked a question about .NET Localization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253614/effective-strategies-for-localization-in-net). It received a bunch of upvotes and some really helpful answers that included a lot of useful knowledge. A few months later it was migrated to [Programmers SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/98358/effective-strategies-for-localization-in-net), where it gained a bunch more votes and some additional answers.

Over the years, I've referred to this question several times, but recently I went looking and found it to be deleted from both sites. It seems that this was the result of a failed attempt to migrate it back to Stack Overflow in 2015 followed by an automatic deletion due to *RemoveRejectedMigrations* at the end of 2016.

While it may be a problem useful information can be automatically deleted from Stack Exchange, my question is about how to recover the answers for this question.

- I have:

  1. Trusted user access to the Stack Overflow question;
  2. OP access to the SoftwareEngineering.SE (formerly Programmers).
- I *undeleted* the Stack Overflow question to see if it would recover the additional answers from SoftwareEngineering.SE, but unfortunately the undeleted post reverted to its previous Stack Overflow state from before it was migrated over to Programmers.SE. **Some answers are missing.**
- I don't have privileges to undelete the SoftwareEngineering.SE question, but I can navigate to it when logged in under my account. (I was the OP). **All but one answer is missing.** My guess is that if I got my SoftwareEngineering.SE reputation up then I could access the record, but it seems like there is an easier/faster way.

Comment: Wait, your questions, combined, don't show all the answers they collected across the two sites -- there are answers that were deleted on both sides? That shouldn't happen, and is an undeniable bug in migration. The rest is just the tedious migration philosophy working more or less as designed (even if nobody really likes the design much these days).

Comment: I guess that you don't see the answers on SoftwareEngineering.SE since they were deleted along with the question, and you don't have privileges to see deleted posts except of those you posted yourself. You'll have to find someone that can un-delete the SoftwareEngineering.SE question for you.

Comment: This seems like a migration bug and probably the reason the post deleted in the first place. One answer failed to get back from SE to SO and so migration engine deleted the whole thread. It is also expected for old SO thread to not have all the answers as they got posted after the first migration. Now, we sure need a feature so we can recover posts or maybe another run of migration engine to recover these useful questions that got deleted for a bug that is definitely inside the migration engine.

Comment: I've undeleted the post on the SoftwareEngineering.SE site. Please let me know if you still have problems accessing your answer.

Comment: @js12 - Thank you.  Unfortunately, it appears to have been automatically redeleted again 2 days later.

Comment: @smartcaveman I'm going to delete the SO version and undelete the Software Engineering version to and see if we can get this to clear up.

Comment: @bluefeet Migration history should be cleared to prevent future RejectedMigration autodeletion.

Comment: @Gerry We unlocked the question on Software Engineering, which prevents it getting picked up by the query that runs those deletions.

Comment: Link to your question https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/98358/effective-strategies-for-localization-in-net